# How to use blob streams in a JPA-compliant way?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, blob

Is there a JPA-compliant way to stream data from and to a database, that is, without using (for example) Hibernate-specific stuff? The solutions I found so far, are based on Hibernate-specific extensions/classes, like accessing the session via EntityManager->getDelegate() etc. to create the corresponding Blob object and attaching it to the database session.

Comment: you mean like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob(int,%20java.io.InputStream)

Comment: yes, indeed. exactly like that.